# How to autoload classes without namespaces with Composer without reinstalling?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, silex

I just need to autoload some classes, and I don't like the psr-0 namespace insanity (no offense).

This used to work just fine in my project:

```
"psr-0": {
    "": [
        "app/controller/",
        "app/model/"
    ]
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work anymore, even though I'm using the same Composer version. I need it for a new project that is also using Silex. Could this be a conflict with Silex?

I know about the "classmap" option, but it's kind of useless because it requires that I run "composer install" every time I add a new class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

Try to use "primitive" JSON properties; not an array (like in your example). 
This works for me with `psr-4` like you say, with `"": "app/"`:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Robbie\\": "core/",
        "": "app/"
    }
},
"require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.2.*"
    } 
}
```

This gives me the `Robbie` namespace under the directory `core`, as an example of sources not controlled by composer, the 3rd party (vendor) Monolog namespace and my default or non-namespace for sources underneath the `app` directory.

After a `composer update`, all of them are available when including the generated autoload.php:

```
<?php    
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
// ...    
?>
```

Comment: I think a combination of giving composer file a name and running composer install composer update composer install composer update did it finally

Comment: @Toskan It did, at least even for me

Answer (score 15):

Use `classmap` in instead of `psr-4`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["models/"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to regenerate the autoload file use `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Yes, this seemed to help also with the snipped of the asker's snippet. So seems like anyway must be explicitly defined, psr is not enabled by default ofc.